# PayPal Payflow Pro with Chained Payments

Tags: paypal, chained, payflowpro

I integrated PayPal Chained Payments API into a website. Now I wonder if there is any way to connect that with PayFlow Pro, for not having the roundtrip to PayPal's site.

I think for security reasons it's not possible to display the payment flow in a modal window. Even with PayFlow Pro? Can somebody confirm that?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: You cant do chanined payments with Payflow.

With the pro products, you can display a modal window or a lightbox or whatever you want.